# performSelector in NSOperation subclass

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, performselector

I couldn't find an answer anywhere else on the net so any help would be appreciated.

I am tying to create a system whereby I can retrieve the results of an NSOperation task, which I understand cannot be done by concrete subclasses such as NSInvocation.

I have an NSOperation subclass (**TheEngine**) which is abstract by convention and must be extended to implement the function `-main`, to include the body of code to execute.

**TheEngine** contains the following initialisation function whose job is simply to note `theSelector` and `theObject` the selector belongs to. It also registers a KV observer for the property `isFinished` :

```
-(id)initWithCallbackSelector:(SEL)theSelector inObject:(id)theObject
```

In my `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` function I would like to call the callback function like so:

```
NSLog(@"Some debug text to ensure this function is being called", nil);
[theObject performSelector:theSelector withObject:someData afterDelay:0];
```

The  whole process goes like this:

**aViewController** fires up an extension of  **TheEngine** - lets say **TheTask** by calling the following and adding it to an operations queue.

```
TheTask* TT = [[TheTask alloc] initWithCallbackSelector:
    @selector(resultHandler:) inObject:theObject];
```

Everything seems to run as expected without any errors or exceptions at all. But when execution reaches the `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` the callback is not actually called. I'm new to Obj-C, so I'm not entirely sure if my understanding of this type of threading is correct.

Here is the entire code:

```
-(id)initWithCallbackSelector:(SEL)theSelector inObject:(id)theObject{

    if([self init]){

        self.selectorsParentObject      =   theObject;
        self.selectorToCallWhenFinished =   theSelector;


        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isFinished" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

        return self;
    }

    return nil; 
}


-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath ofObject:(id)theObject change:(NSDictionary*)theChange context:(void*)theContext{

    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"isFinished"]){

        NSLog(@"activity is finished with change: %@", theChange);

        NSLog(@"target object: %@", self.selectorsParentObject);
        NSLog(@"target selector: %@", NSStringFromSelector(self.selectorToCallWhenFinished));

        //[self performSelectorOnMainThread:self.selectorToCallWhenFinished withObject:self.resultData waitUntilDone:NO];
        [self.selectorsParentObject performSelector:@selector(selectorToCallWhenFinished) withObject:self.resultData afterDelay:0];
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your `NSOperation` is likely running on a background thread. If that thread goes away, or if that thread fails to pump its run loop, then your call to `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` will not fire. You commented out a call to `performSelectorOnMainThread:...`. Did this work?

You probably should be running this on the main thread or running this with `performSelector:withObject:` (without the `afterDelay:`). `performSelector:withObject:` does not require a run loop.

Comment: thanks for the tip, your hunch turned out correct - I will post the changes I made :)

Answer (score 0):

As Rob suggested, the code was running in a background thread, as was the call `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`

I had initially changed the code so that the selector was fired on the main thread with `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(runCallback) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];`.

But in this case the main thread turns out to be the **TheTask** and an exception was thrown as **TheTask** does not own `theSelector`. To correct this, I created an extra function `-runCallback` and fired it from

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath ofObject:(id)theObject change:(NSDictionary*)theChange context:(void*)theContext{

    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"isFinished"]){

        NSLog(@"activity is finished with change: %@", theChange);

        NSLog(@"target object: %@", self.selectorsParentObject);
        NSLog(@"target selector: %@", NSStringFromSelector(self.selectorToCallWhenFinished));



        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(runCallback) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

        //[self performSelectorOnMainThread:self.selectorToCallWhenFinished withObject:self.resultData waitUntilDone:NO];
        //[self.selectorsParentObject performSelector:@selector(selectorToCallWhenFinished) withObject:self.resultData afterDelay:0];
    }
}
```

and in the `-runCallback`:

```
-(void)runCallback{

    [self.selectorsParentObject performSelector:self.selectorToCallWhenFinished withObject:self.resultData afterDelay:0];

}
```

This called `theSelector` in **TheTask** with the correct data.
Thanks for participating :)